# Kali linux-Wiped entire file system accidentally

Tags: linux, shell, rm, recovery

Something pretty bad just happened

I was testing some build files I had made as root, and tried to delete the contents of one of the directories the script had made, but I forgot to move to it and ended up running `rm *` on the root directory. Initially I though it wouldn't do anything cause I didn't specify recursive, but it ended up wiping pretty much everything on the PC. I stupidly restarted the computer and now it wont boot as there are no init files, is there anything at all I can do or do I have to wipe my SD card and reinstall kali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was testing some build files I had made as root, and tried to delete
> the contents of one of the directories the script had made, but I
> forgot to move to it and ended up running rm * on the root directory.

Kali is somewhat unfriendly and does not have user recovery tools for deleted files.

If you have deleted everything, you need to reinstall Kali again.

Posted from my Kali 2022.1 machine.

Comment: Ok, what I feared. Thank you.